# URL has been mapped outside of hosts

Tags: dns, spoofing

If I ping pagead2.googlesyndication.com, it goes to some spam IP in Ukraine, rather than google. It's not in my hosts file. I can't override it with my hosts file either Where would it be?

Comment: Change your DNS server?

Comment: @Darius Thank you. I've tried this. Still spams.

Comment: Out of curiosity, you do realize that URL particularly is for Google ad network right? Sometimes the ad network does not know what kind of advertising/spam is being served.

Comment: @Darius Yes, I did know that. It's not that it's just serving garbage. It's actually pointing to the wrong IP.

Comment: What IP address do you get?

Comment: I would guess this URL resolves to a WIDE range of possible IP addresses depending on a WIDE selection of variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like somebody did hack my router and changed the primary DNS Server. I had to change that and then Reset WINSOCK entries and IPv4/6 TCP/IP stack to installation defaults by running the following on the command line:

```
netsh winsock reset catalog
netsh int ipv4 reset reset.log
netsh int ipv6 reset reset.log
```

I'm still not sure why it didn't affect all devices but that seems to have fixed it.